# Could not save PDF in Photoshop 7.0

Tags: photoshop

I have created my resume in Photoshop 7.0 and when I want to save it as a PDF, it's showing up errors:

> Could not save Filename because of a program error.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gYd2-RUY_s) actually solved the problem for me.

1. Navigate to `Edit -> Preferences -> File Handling...`.
2. Untick `Save to Background`.
3. Try saving the PSD as something like `a.pdf`.

This solved my issue when I ran into the same error.  I'm using Adobe Photoshop CC.

Comment: Go to File->Save As->Select pdf from drop down-> There is an option Quality -> Select it as 'HIGH'(instead of MAXIMUM) and it will be saved as pdf. This worked for me...